# Reasoning in first order logic

Tags: nlp, first-order-logic

I have been reading about converting natural language sentences into first order logic and I was curious about how logical reasoning can be expressed in first order logic.

I want to know how to convert sentences like 'Event A occurs because of Event B' into first order logic.

An example of such a sentence I can think of is:

```
X is evil; Because X is evil, X kills Y.
```

How is the above sentence represented in first order logic?

The solution I thought about is:

```
Evil(X) -> Kills(X, Y)
```

However I am not sure if this is correct or not as I cannot find examples of similar sentences online. If this is wrong, why is it wrong and how do I correct it?

Comment: For tools that do this sort of thing - see Jerry Hobbs' convertor (http://www.isi.edu/%7Ehobbs/LFToolkit/index.html) and Johan Bos C&C tools (http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/meaningfactory/)

Comment: Event A occurring before Event B, can be interpreted as knowing Event B will tell you Event A is already occurred. Hence B imples A.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fact that this kind of connection such as "because" is problematic as it does not stand to the "logic connective" standards. You cannot validate the conditions under which the reasoning took place. 
For exapmle: 
"I fell because I ran fast".
You cannot validate that I fell because I ran fast. Someone might have pushed me, or I stumbled on an object across the road. That means you need some extra information, more details about the event, and first order logic does not deal with that. It only deals with logic connectives, which are connectives that require no further information about the event in order to validate or contradict the proposition.